# Google OAuth does not return phone number in android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase, xamarin.forms

I have xamarin forms app where I have implemented Google Oauth.
I am able to log in through OAuth and able to get token successfully.
after decoding the jwt token I saw the token does not have a phone number field which is been linked to a google account.

so my question is do I need to do anything additional to get the phone number field?
or is there any other API that needs to be called to get phone no by passing token.

I am decoding my token data at Node Js server so would request if someone have any idea how can I
retrieve users phone number associated with google account